# How do I write a query related to count

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables such as `Car` and `Driver`. `Car` table has two columns. which are `car_id` and `car_name`. `Driver` table also has two columns. which are `driver_id` and `car_type`.

**Cars**

| car_id | car_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Audi |
| 2 | BMW |
| 3 | Ferrari |

**Drivers**

| driver_id | car_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BMW |
| 1 | Audi |
| 1 | Ferrari |
| 2 | Audi |
| 2 | Cheverolet |
| 2 | Tata |
| 3 | Ferrari |

How do I find which driver is driving more than two cars?

Comment: Car_id values 1 2 3 and car_name audi, bmw and ferrari...     driver_id values 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3 and car_type values as bmw,ferrari,audi,ferrari,chevrolet,bmw,audi,ferrari

Comment: Probably using a HAVING clause https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj14854.html

Answer (score 0):

By using the Having clause

```
SELECT Driver_id
FROM Driver
GROUP BY Driver_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tables have surrogate primary keys but the `Driver` table uses the car name, not id, to relate cars to drivers.

So you can find the drivers with more than one car without needing to join to the car table (unless you need the `car_id` value)

The query needs to count the distinct type of car grouped by `driver_id`, having a count of car type greater than one.

From the information in that sentence you should be able to look up how to write it in SQL ;)

If the `Driver` table has a unique constraint on the two fields `driver_id`/`car_type` then you can use the query Dijkgraaf posted and not worry about the type of car they drive.

From the data you have shown there can't be any referential constraint (foreign key) of the cars drivers drive because you have
`Cheverolet` (sic), `Tata`, and `Ferrari` in the `Driver` table but those cars are not in the `Car` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Driver_id
FROM YourTable
Where COUNT(Driver_id) > 1
```